# docker login fails -> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority .. "crypto/rsa: verification error"

Tags: macos, docker, vagrant, coreos

I have created a private docker registry which is fronted by NGINX. NGINX is where the ssl terminates.

**I am obfuscating my domain by using my-domain.com for the purpose of this question.**

I am using OSX 10.10.3 which has boot2docker installed. But it should be noted that the workflow of Vagrant + CoreOS + Docker shouldn't involve boot2docker since I am having issues within the VM(CoreOS) and not the Host(OSX).

I am using Vagrant to spin up a local CoreOS VM from this [box](http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/681.0.0/coreos_production_vagrant.box). I then ssh into an instance of that VM and attempt to issue the following command

```
$ docker login docker.my-domain.com
```

I am then prompted for my username, password, email as expected; and I supply my details.

Note: I am able to issue the above command in the Host OS (OSX) as expected and able to successfully login (generates the ~/.dockercfg file).

I get the following error:

```
FATA[0008] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://docker.my-domain.com/v1/_ping: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to 
verify candidate authority certificate "*.my-domain.com"). If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS 
with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry docker.my-domain.com` to the daemon's 
arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; 
simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.my-domain.com/ca.crt
```

I have copied over my ca.crt from my self signing. I can confirm that CoreOS is able to connect properly to my server over SSL. I ran this command

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.my-domain.com/ca.crt -connect docker.my-domain.com:443
```

And I get the expected 'Verify return code: 0 (ok)'. This leads me to believe its docker that seems to be having a problem.

```
$ docker version (from within CoreOS VM)
Client version: 1.6.1-rc2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 17f157d-dirty
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.1-rc2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 17f157d-dirty
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

After all this, I am not sure what I need to try next. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a two part issue. The first issue was that when I placed the certificate file(ca.crt) in the relative /etc/ssl/certs/ folder, I didn't rename the original file with the .pem extension. This meant that when I ran the the update-ca-certificates to install my custom certificate on the client machine, it wasn't getting recognized. This was hiding the second and main issue.

I wasn't using the correct certificate file. Once I used the correct certificate file, and I renamed the file to have the .pem extension I ran update-ca-certificates and then issued the login command and it worked.

I assume I mush have installed the correct version of the cert correctly on my host OSX machine, which is why it worked there but not in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly useful for other people running into this.. If you are using intermediate certificates, the ca.pem file that docker sees *MUST* have both the root and the intermediate certificates in it. If you are using client certs, you almost certainly want the full cert chain in your ~/.docker/ca.pem file as well.